# How to calculate the difference in months between two dates in TOSCA?

Tags: tosca

Date 1: 10/25/2020
Date 2: 01/25/2021
Difference = 3

What is the formula to find the difference between two dates in months in TOSCA?

Answer (score 1):

WEEKDAY :

To find the day of the week of a given date
{CALC[WEEKDAY(DATE(2018,3,18))]}

```
        Expected result: For the above-given date, the result will be 1 (Sunday)

        Sunday= 1, Monday=2, Tuesday=3,
```

Wednesday=4, Thursday=5, Friday=6 Saturday=7

DATEDIF :
To find the difference between two given dates.

```
        {CALC[DATEDIF(DATE(2018,2,10),DATE(2018,2,21), """d""")]}

        Expected result: Above expression will give you the results as 11 (Difference between the given dates is 11 days.)
```

IF :
Given two dates we find which date is bigger amongst the two dates

```
      {CALC[IF(DATE(2018,1,3)>DATE(2018,3,24),"""True""","""False""")]}
```

Expected results: This expression gives you the result as false as the first given date is smaller than the second one.

Comment: Please specify the language (along with the code) so that we can dig it out and provide better explanation..

Comment: TOSCA is a script less tool, so we don't use any code particularly.

DATEDIF : To find the difference between two given dates.

        {CALC[DATEDIF(DATE(2018,2,10),DATE(2018,2,21), """d""")]}

        Expected result: Above expression will give you the results as 11 (Difference between the given dates is 11 days.)

We use the above approach you have mentioned. So, may be in a similar way we can find out how to find the difference in months.

Comment: I see, I'll post if I encounter the solution